# Mongo Shell print is not displaying?

Tags: mongodb, shell, robo3t

So I am trying to compare a simple comma delimited list to the documents in my collection. This is my code:

```
var file = cat("Price Level V.csv");
var skus = file.split("\n");
for(var i = 0; i < skus.length; i++) {
    var vasku = skus[i].split(',');
    db.getCollection('skus').findOne({sku:vasku[0]}, function(err, mydoc) {
        if(err)
            print(err);

        if(mydoc == null) {
            print('NF');
        } else if(mydoc.VA == vasku[1]) {
            print('Correct');
        } else {
            print('Incorrect');
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason, I am not seeing anything pop up in the shell for all my print statements. It should at least print 'Incorrect', right?

Comment: Have you checked if you actually enter the loop? Or could skus be empty, e.g. because the csv file is empty or could not be read?

Comment: I can print file and skus and they are both populated. I am doing this through robomongo if that matters? But it may not be hitting it because nothing is printing. I simply do not know why it is not entering the loop...

Answer (score 0):

If the loop is entered and the skus collection is not empty, then this can happen if you misspell the collection name of the model that You try to query (I see that from time to time when someone writes the collection name in camelCase).

It's a long shot but maybe the model name in the db is actually skuss (second 's' added for plural form)?